# Removed component on motherboard

Tags: resistors, computers

(Is this even a electronics related or computer related?)

Does anyone owns a Dell Optiplex 780 DT? I was adding a graphics card and I accidentally bumped the bracket into the PCB and I checked the board, it was missing a resistor labeled R2015, and now my computer doesn't detect my graphics card. I don't have a picture but it's the right upper part of the slot.

[image: this is the pictre]

This is where the resistor placed (sorry it's blurred.)

Comment: "Sorry it's blurred" - so blurred you can't even see it.

Comment: In any case there are frequently times when footprints on PCBs are left unpopulated intententionally. Unless there are obvious remnants of solder joints (square imprints in the pad), the component wasn't knocked off.

Comment: it's knocked off the board since you can tell a component was soldered there. (if my picture was clear you can really tell *sigh*)

Comment: Do you have a relevant-to-this-site question?

Comment: What do you mean? (sorry my english understanding is not that good)

Comment: A warm welcome to the site. I'm afraid the site is for electronics design questions and answers, so this question is outside of the scope of the site. You can take the tour and it will explain all this for you. Your question will be closed but you can delete it yourself before any downvotes reduce your Reputation. Again, welcome.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Found the schematic]
I found a schematic for my board and it's a 0 ohm resistor (jumper)